# In Graphics, a button without action will not work?

Tags: graphics, button

A minimal example:

```
Graphics@Button[Disk[]]
```

will yield error message

> Button is not a Graphics primitive or directive.

But if you drop `Graphics@` part in the code above, generating a button:

[image]

Then you *edit* the output, simply *apprending* `Graphics@` to it. And viola!

[image]

I have no idea why this aproach will work but the code won't.

So is this the correct behavior? Can we call this a (tiny) bug?

By the way, the error message is actually very misleading. A button that really *does* something (anything) will work perfectly well in Graphics. For example:

```
Graphics@Button[Disk[], bla]
```

will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Documentation pages both for `Graphics` and `Button` only the two-argument form of `Button` is mentioned as a wrapper allowed inside of `Graphics`. So I would not say that the behavior you describe contradicts the Documentation.

From the other side, for what purpose may you need a knowingly inoperative `Button` inside of `Graphics`? This approach looks like a wrong idea on its own, so I would not complain that it produces an error message. `Button` without the second argument is just a useless wrapper and the error message correctly warns that you are doing something wrong.

You have already provided an easy workaround - simple addition of the second argument of `Button` (even `Null`) "fixes" this: `Graphics@Button[Disk[], ]` does not produce the error message.

So there is nothing that can be called even a minor bug.

Why then your workaround through editing the output by prepending `Graphics@` to it works? Let us see what the output `Cell` actually contains by appending `//InputForm` and evaluating inside of a Notebook:

[image: screenshot]

You see that the `Button` in the output `Cell` actually contains four arguments (but it is still the one-argument form of `Button` with options appended)! So the explanation is simple: *Mathematica* simply checks if `Button` contains only one argument and complains in this case. It seems to be the intended behavior but poorly implemented: more general case of one-argument `Button` with options was not considered by the developer. So it is not a bug, just careless without harmful consequences.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. And I share many common arguments with you. What concerns me, and had baffled me, is the misleading message that this behavior may cause. As a newcomer who is not familiar with button in graphics, when I was trying to implement such a thing, I wasn't setting everything up in the first place, but firstly trying to see if an (empty) button will wrok well in graphics. By no means I would have known, in advance, that an empty button is considered "inappropriate" in this scenario. To make things worse, (continued)...

Comment: an error message which states that a button will not work in graphics is certainly not helpful. I think similar "accident" may likely happen to other new users. And this can be really confusing for us.

Comment: And my sincere thanks to you, for providing an thorough analysis on this (possibly trivial) question. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the Accept. I agree that such a message is confusing for a new user if it face it without previous experience with *Mathematica*. Generally there are infinite number of such issues. And there are still at least hundreds of well-known issues which trouble newcomers for decades all the time: see [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/280). Unfortunately the politics of the company still does not coincide well with expectations of the customers.